# Grails 2.5.4 / Spring Security Rest 1.5.4 - Validating token

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

What I'm trying to do is login a user and get a token back (this part works). Then I want to validate this token every time I access an API path. I'm obviously doing something wrong, maybe I don't fully understand what the Spring Security Rest plugin is actually supposed to do but whenever I call an API path and send the token all I get back is the Spring Security login page's html. I'm using Boomerang Soap and Rest Client. Here's what I'm sending.

Login Request (path: `http://localhost:7070/backend3/api/login`):

```
{
    "username": "test@user.com",
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Login Response:

```
{
    "username": "test@user.com",
    "roles": [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIU.", // shortened token to conserve space
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIU." // shortened token to conserve space
}
```

So clearly this part works fine. Then I try to use the token I received from the above's response to access my API. Keep in mind that in my config under Spring Security's rules I have `'/external/**':['ROLE_USER']`. If I change that to `['permitAll']` then it I gain access no problem but then spring security is effectively useless.

API Request (path: `http://localhost:7070/backend3/external/user/info`)

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIU" // shortened token to conserve space
}
```

And this then return's the standard login page's html. I've tried sending all sorts of combinations of stuff like `access_token`, `username`, `token_type`, `roles`. I have even tried a different format of the `access_token`; `"Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU"` which I found on the [docs](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.4/docs/guide/tokenValidation.html) but nothing works.

Can someone please explain to me how to go about this because the docs assume a lot of prior knowledge which I clearly don't have. I'll post (the relevant parts of) my Config and UrlMappings files below for further clarification. Please let me know if I need to supply more info, I just really need to get this working as I've been stuck on it for 2 weeks. Thanks

Config:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.crastino.domain.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.crastino.domain.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.crastino.domain.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                ['permitAll'],
    '/index':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
    '/external/**':     ['ROLE_USER']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/auth/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter', // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl='/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode=401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName='username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName='password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl='/auth/logout'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useUUID=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.active=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.endpointUrl='/auth/validate'
```

Ps. I have also tried adding the path I'm trying to access to this part `grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap` by adding `'/external/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'` to the end of the array

UrlMappings:

```
group("/external") {
    "/user/info" (controller: 'external', action: 'Service_UserInfo')
}
```

Comment: Try changing the URL mapping to to `group("/api/external") {` and access resource as `http://localhost:7070/backend3/api/external/user/info`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My boss managed to get it working for me. The main issue seems to have been the controller I was trying to access. The controller now looks like this:

```
// package statement
// import statements
import grails.rest.RestfulController

class UserController extends RestfulController<User> {

    def springSecurityService

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }

    @Secured(['permitAll'])
    def index() {
        // use this method to test the api without authenticating
        // if you are authenticated though, it'll let you know.
        if(springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            render(text:[loggedIn:'true'] as JSON)
        } else {
            render(text:[loggedIn:'false'] as JSON)
        }
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def listContacts() {
        // needs authentication to access so if you call this method
        // through the api and it returns users you're golden
        def result = User.findAll()
        respond result, [excludes: ['class']]
    }
}
```

So the key differences seem to be importing and extending the RestfulController, the responseFormats and the constructor. I don't actually know what any of that means or how it works so if someone wants to edit an explanation into this answer be my guest.

Another key mistake I made was in the rest call. I would call /api/login with my username/password as json parameters which would return the `access_token` no problem. But then when I wanted to access, for example, /user/listContacts I would send the `access_token` as a parameter with key `access_token`, instead of sending it as a header with key `X-Auth-Token`. Doing that seems to have been part of the fix.

My boss also removed most of the crap (related to Spring Security and Rest) that was in my config file, so I'll just provide these changes too. Note that the controller, config and API call was the only necessary changes so everything else in your project can be kept standard (aside from including the plugins in your BuildConfig).

```
//Config for Spring Security REST plugin
//login
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.crastino.domain.AuthenticationToken'
```

And that was it. Also, [here's](https://github.com/dmahapatro/grails-spring-security-rest-sample/) a link to an example project that helped a lot.

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is: your url `http://localhost:7070/backend3/external/user/info` is not under /api/** so the regular spring security filter chain is being invoked instead of the rest api filter chain.

Try

```
/external/**: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'
```

Also by default the bearer token is used. so you have to pass the bearer token in authorization header unless you have changed the header name and disabled the bearer token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I included the above in the `filterChain.chainMap` (you forgot to put the left side of the colon in quotes). And now I'm sending `"Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIU"` (still shortened) still to the same URL and I'm still getting the login page back. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: By default, the plugin generates JWT tokens. Note that when using JWT, you can't plug any other token generator. like uuid or secure random.

Also try putting grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.active = true

Comment: When you access just /api/xxx without passing token, what response do you get back ? Do you get login page ? Login page being returned indicates that the rest filter chain is not being applied.